# Tic Tac Toe game - object oriented Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, tic-tac-toe

I've written my first project which is Tic Tac Toe. Everything is working correctly. I'm here to get some advice about my code. I want to be this code as much object oriented as it can be. I divided every method into new class to keep it clear.

The only thing which is "probably" un-object oriented  is "static" board. I don't know how to get rid of it.

**Main Class**

```
package TicTacToeGame;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game allGame = new Game();
    allGame.StartGame();
}    
}
```

**Game Class**

```
package TicTacToeGame;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Game {
PrintBoard map = new PrintBoard();
private FullPlace fullPlace = new FullPlace();
ChangePlayer playerChanger = new ChangePlayer();
WinnerConditions winner = new WinnerConditions();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
char[][] board = PrintBoard.board;
NoPlace noPlace = new NoPlace();
private int row, col;


void StartGame() {


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            board[i][j] = '_';
        }
    }


    map.printBoard();
    while (winner.Winner()) {

        row = input.nextInt();
        col = input.nextInt();
        if (row > 3 || col > 3) {
            System.out.println("You've inputed place, which is out of the board!\nTry again!");

        } else {
            if (fullPlace.isFull(row, col)) {
                System.err.println("The place is taken");

            } else {
                board[row - 1][col - 1] = playerChanger.getTurn();
                map.printBoard();
                playerChanger.whichPlayer();
            }

        }


    }
    playerChanger.whichPlayer();
    System.out.println("the winner is " + playerChanger.getTurn());
}
}
```

**Winner Condition Class**

```
package TicTacToeGame;

public class WinnerConditions {
char[][] board = PrintBoard.board;

public boolean Winner() {

    if (board[0][0] != '_' && board[0][0] == board[0][1] && board[0][0] == board[0][2])
        return false;
    if (board[1][0] != '_' && board[1][0] == board[1][1] && board[1][0] == board[1][2])
        return false;
    if (board[2][0] != '_' && board[2][0] == board[2][1] && board[2][0] == board[2][2])
        return false;
    if (board[0][0] != '_' && board[0][0] == board[1][0] && board[0][0] == board[2][0])
        return false;
    if (board[0][1] != '_' && board[0][1] == board[1][1] && board[0][1] == board[2][1])
        return false;
    if (board[0][2] != '_' && board[0][2] == board[1][2] && board[0][2] == board[2][2])
        return false;
    if (board[0][0] != '_' && board[0][0] == board[1][1] && board[0][0] == board[2][2])
        return false;
    if (board[0][2] != '_' && board[0][2] == board[1][1] && board[0][2] == board[2][0])
        return false;

    return true;
}

}
```

**No Place Class**

```
package TicTacToeGame;

public class NoPlace {
char[][] board = PrintBoard.board;

public boolean OutOfBoard(int row, int col) {
    if (row > 3 || col > 3) {
        System.err.println("There is no row or column");
        return true;

    }
    return false;

}
}
```

**Print Board Class**

```
package TicTacToeGame;

public class PrintBoard {
public static char[][] board = new char[3][3];


public void printBoard() {

    System.out.println("-------------");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print("| ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

            System.out.print(board[i][j] + " | ");

        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    System.out.println("-------------");

}
}
```

**Change Player Class**

```
package TicTacToeGame;

public class ChangePlayer {
public char turn = 'X';

public void whichPlayer() {
    if (turn == 'X') {
        turn = 'O';
    } else {
        turn = 'X';

    }
}

public char getTurn() {
    return turn;
}


}
```

**Full Place Class**

```
package TicTacToeGame;

public class FullPlace {
char[][] board = PrintBoard.board;

public boolean isFull(int row, int col) {
    if (board[row - 1][col - 1] == 'X' ||
        board[row - 1][col - 1] == 'O') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


}
```

Comment: Your class modeling is strange, not object-oriented. Where you introduce separate classes like `FullPlace`, I'd create methods on the Game class instead. A helpful start for modeling is describing your task in English, and representing nouns as classes and verbs as methods.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff If I understand rigthly, I should remove classes with one method and create in Game Class? What do you mean about "a helpful start for modeling is describing your task in English"? I just wanted to create Tic Tac Toe Game :D There isn't any task.

Comment: Most of your objects are stateless. There are reasons to create such things, but not in your program. An object to represent the contents of the board is legitimate, but it shouldn't be called `PrintBoard`, since that's hardly the sole purpose of representing the board. You can avoid the static member by _passing_ the board to any method that needs it. An object to keep track of which player is playing is OK too, and an object to hold both of those. With just console input and output, there really isn't much else in this game to use objects for.

Comment: Actually, it is also possible to turn each individual _cell_ in the board into an object. Perhaps a little bit of overkill for a program like this but it at least makes some kind of sense with regard to the model.

Comment: You should consider what the purpose of each class is. Does it represent some object in your problem domain, such as a tic-tac-toe grid? Is it part of a design pattern that employs this class along with some others? You _can_ have a one-method class, but there should be a reason. For example, if you had ten different ways to draw an X or O on the grid, it _might_ make sense to have a one-function class to implement each way--there's a pattern for such things.

Comment: One _good_ thing about this program is you have a reasonable number of methods. For example, `outOfBoard` is a good method to have, although you forgot to use it where you could. If you had a more complicated board (like Connect Four) you might want subroutines in your `winner` function, but here you can get away without them.

Comment: Take care about naming, too. According to https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2-specific-identifier-names, your package name should have no upper-case letters (`tictactoe` would be OK), and methods should start with lower-case letters (some of yours are OK, but `OutOfBoard` and `Winner` are not). These things affect how your code is displayed by StackExchange (see the coloring of different names in the code above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your code.

## OOP

OOP doesn't mean to "split up" code into random classes.

The ultimate goal of OOP is to reduce code duplication, improve readability and support reuse as well as extending the code.

Doing OOP means that you follow certain principles which are (among others):

- information hiding / encapsulation
- single responsibility
- separation of concerns
- KISS (Keep it simple (and) stupid.)
- DRY (Don't repeat yourself.)
- "Tell! Don't ask."
- Law of demeter ("Don't talk to strangers!")

E.g.: in your class `TicTacToeGame` you access a field in the class `PrintBoard`. This is a violation of the *information hiding / encapsulation* principle. 
The cause why you "can't get rid" of that static access is that you should not access this field from outside at all. The method in you `FullPlace` class schould be in class `PrintBoard` (which should not be named with the prefix "print"). 
In turn the class`FullPlace` should't exist at all.

## Naming

Finding good names is the hardest part in programming, so always take your time to think about the names of your identifiers.

#### Naming Conventions

Please read (and follow) the 
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

#### misleading naming

Some of your identifiers have somewhat misleading names, eg. `ChangePlayer` and `PrintBoard` which look like  method names since they start with a *verb* but they are classes. 
But classes don't *do* something. They *are* something which is *able to do* something.

## Magic numbers

Your code has some magic numbers. This are literal values with a special meaning like here:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
```

You should either use constants with meaningful names like

```
private static final int GAME_FIELD_SIZE =3;
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < GAME_FIELD_SIZE; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < GAME_FIELD_SIZE; j++) {
```

or use existing constraints like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
```